When using HTML in a JTextPane (JTextEditor) how can I get back what I put in?
Say I set the text on a JTextPane with code like
JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
textPane.setContentType("text/html");
String text = "Some <b>html</b> text...";
HTMLDocument doc = (HTMLDocument) textPane.getDocument();
HTMLEditorKit editorKit = (HTMLEditorKit) textPane.getEditorKit();
try {
    doc.remove(0, doc.getLength());
    editorKit.insertHTML(doc, 0, text, 0, 0, null);
} catch (BadLocationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}

I want to be able to get the same text back that I put in such that I can do something like this:
String returnedText = textPane.getText(); // or whatever
if ( text.equals(returnedText) ) {
    System.out.println("I want this to be executed");
}

Is this even possible? Are there any methods classes that can help with this? Or is it always the case that the text I set is modified and I can never get back what I put in.

If you are careful about the html and provide it all, getText should get what you put in, but you might need to adjust the whitespace somewhat, or just scan characters only when comparing

The documentation for both HTMLEditorKit and HTMLDocument make it abundantly clear that extensive rewriting of the HTML can take place. So you probably can't do this. @g00se

I get the impression that you are asking whether your proposed solution is implementable and that makes me think that maybe there is an alternative way to achieve your desired result. Can you explain what made you decide that you need this functionality?

I suspect that you're going to need to drop down to the document level, but even then, I'm not sure you're going to find a simple solution for your problem

The reason I want to do this comes down to the basic problem that Swing allows the edits to come from two sources: 1) the user through the operating system and 2) the application through programatic method calls. Fundamentally, I want to be able to distinguish between the two when receiving events (like DocumentEvents or MouseEvents or KeyEvents, or whatever). Swing does not keep track of whether the event comes from the user or the program and how my code responds to the two needs to be different. Why? Because if my code updates the UI then it does not need to respond to the events.

Now, before anyone gives solutions like "remove the event listener" or create a variable that flags whether to process the event or something, please know that I've been at this for months and read countless SO questions, documentation, and reverse engineered swing components. My current solution, which works for JTextFields and many other text based components, is to compare the text already in the field to the text about to be set. This gives me useful information and has worked well in essentially breaking an infinite event cycle. But it doesn't work if JTextPane mangles the text.

If the answer is, there is no way to reliably set the text and then get what was passed in to the setter, then that is my answer.

@Jason how about using a separate variable to keep track of exactly the text that was passed to the setter?

Thanks @masterxilo, that's ultimately what I did.

Even that solution has some challenges though because the ultimate goal was to handle text change events initiated by the user. That means events are fired and have downstream consequences (in multiple threads). Furthermore, Swing does this interesting thing where it changes the text to the empty string before setting the text... that is... if I call setText on the JTextPane with a string "hello" then the text is first set to the blank string! So now... does the text in the text field match this variable that I just used to store text from the setter? Or did the user type something?
